# What was Ram planning to do with Saroo in Lion?

Tags: lion

In the movie Lion, what was the duo of Noor and Ram planning to do with Saroo? Or is it left ambiguous? (in this case what are the most likely candidates?)

Comment: I think it's ambiguous in the film.  However, the movie was [based on a memoir](https://www.amazon.com/Long-Way-Home-Memoir/dp/0425276198), so reading that might shed some light on what was happening.  (That is, if the scene isn't a fabrication made up for the film.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was somewhat ambiguous. There was certainly a strong implication that Ram was up to something sexual, the way he lays on the bed next to Saroo and checks out his physique. But it could also have been that they were just going to adopt him out like what actually ended up happening to him. We never really find out.

It also seemed like the people who ran the orphanage were "lending" out some of the children for something lascivious at night. It seemed like they were having Shondeep, the child who keeps hitting himself, do something with men who would come by at night. They tell the men, "Have him back by morning."

Likewise, it seemed like the men chasing the children in the tunnels were either selling them into slavery or using them in some similar way. My point being, there seemed to be a large market for young children for a variety of illegal purposes in India at that time.